# How to get (selected) control highlight as it's done in visual studio wpf editor

Tags: c#, wpf, select, wpf-controls, highlight

Visual studio:

[image: this is in Visual Studio]

I'm trying to highlight a control as it is done in Visual Studio xaml editor. I have tried to do this by just building another control (highlighter control) over the selected control. But this will not work if the selected control's parent is rotated.

Mine:

[image]

```
    <Canvas x:Name="parent" Margin="0,0,2,-3" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#FF003AFF">
        <Grid x:Name="highlighter" Height="90" Width="128" MouseUp="mu_MouseUp" 
              MouseMove="Drase_MouseMove" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="45" Cursor="Arrow">
            <Border  x:Name="muhhh" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=highlighter, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mu, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FFFF0C6F" Background="{x:Null}"
                     BorderThickness="1" Cursor="Arrow" />

        </Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="selecteble1" Height="210" Width="485" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="205"
                Background="#FF09E4DA" MouseDown="selecteble1_MouseDown" 
                MouseLeftButtonDown="selecteble1_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                MouseLeftButtonUp="selecteble1_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="selecteble1_MouseMove">
            <Canvas x:Name="selecteble2" Height="135" Width="140" Canvas.Left="230"
                    Canvas.Top="35" Background="#FF0D302F" MouseDown="selecteble1_MouseDown" 
                    MouseLeftButtonDown="selecteble1_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                    MouseLeftButtonUp="selecteble1_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="selecteble1_MouseMove"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

```
    private void posi(Canvas selection)
        {
            Canvas parent = highlighter.Parent as Canvas;

            highlighter.Width = selection.ActualWidth;
            highlighter.Height = selection.ActualHeight;
            Point p = selection.TransformToAncestor(parent).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            Canvas.SetLeft(mu, p.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(mu, p.Y);
            highlighter.RenderTransform = selection.RenderTransform;
        }

//mouse event on selecteble1 and selecteble1 posi is called
```

Rotated:

[image]
[image]

By the way `highlighter.RenderTransform = "selection.parent".RenderTransform;` will not work, as the selection is also rotatable. So please if there is a better way to do this I'll be very thankful if you could help me to complete it.

Comment: It looks like an [`Adorner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview) would fit well here. According to [this question on msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0630621-0245-4be0-acc2-8daf9a78e52b/transformations-on-adornedelement-are-also-applied-to-adorner?forum=wpf) it appears they automatically inherit any transforms applied to their target.